# How does webpack know which files in the built folder to load?

Tags: webpack

If we have webpack create bundles in a "built" folder, I'm assuming there would be a manifest file generated somewhere so that it knows which files to load, when needed?

Just curious where this manifest file is?

The issue I'm trying to solve is that when we do a fresh deployment, the old webpack bundles will no longer exist in the "built" folder (using hashed file names), and so I'm hoping to find a way (putting a cache expiry on the manifest file perhaps) so that if the browser can't find a webpack bundle file to load, then it will try and reload the manifest file completely to find the new file names?

Comment: It will make a bundle for you, and if you use something like HTML plugin it will make an HTML page for you with a script tag in it with the bundle as the source which will allow you to serve the content of `built`, but I'm not really sure what you're getting at with this "manifest" and webpack "loading" files. It doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The issue we face is that we have a SPA web application.  If the user loads the application in their browser at 9am, and we do a fresh server deployment at 10am, then navigational links etc may return a 404 because the version of the webpack file that they loaded at 9am is referencing old bundled information.  Trying to figure out a nicer way to have the browser refresh its bundles

Comment: Links? You mean the `src` attribute in a script tag? Wouldn't the newly deployed HTML reference the newly deployed scripts' filenames?

Comment: Bad choice of words on my part.  Essentialy, we might be requiring resources that no longer exist after the fresh deployment.  I'd like a way to have the browser reload it's bundles after deployment.